# Binance Stream Data End

Tags: javascript, api, websocket, binance

I'm using websockets for stream. For example klines. But that's too much entry. If I retrieve the 1h kline, I just need open and close prices so there is no need to get the middle ones. How can I do that? If I need 4h kline, just need that at the close.

I'm using the "symbol@kline_interval" stream.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the kline stream:

- A kline is valid for a specific minute. So in the first second of a new minute you get a kline with zero volume and and only the open price is sure for now.
- On every change that happens to the kline, you will receive an update.
- When the minute ends, you will receive the last kline for this minute, then also close price, volume and lowest/highest price are sure now.

Just be sure you got the last one:

```
if data['event_time'] >= data['kline']['kline_close_time']:
```

Best regards,
Oliver